# Drag out swift View Controller from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When dragging from the object library to the storyboard, it seems the default view controllers are obj-c.

Is there any way to drag out a swift View Controller? Or make swift the default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewControllers or other components are not tied to obj-C or swift.
 Just make sure when you create your new project to select the proper language you want to develop with : 
[image]